# How does the Yak-130 fly with blocked engine inlets?

Tags: aerodynamics, jet-engine, fighter

In this **Yakovlev Yak-130** youtube video you can see at [2:45](https://youtu.be/_cyPK36qsY8?si=MMfbZtFAdXWpQDcV&t=160) where it closes the inlets(something I've never seen before, I've only seen the typical engine inlet covers) and then it does a perfect take off (at 2:58) like there's nothing wrong with closing the inlets.

Can someone explain how is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The inlets are closed in order to avoid FOD (foreign object damage) when taking off from unprepared fields. Anyway when the main inlets close, above the fuselage two other inlets open, as visible for example in the following picture ([source](https://wallup.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/360173-aircraft-the-yak-130-combat-trainer-jet-military.jpg)):

[image]

I think that this solution was imposed by the compactness of the airframe and the proximity of the front landing gear to the inlets, which worsen FOD ingestion.

As [pointed out by Peter Kämpf](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/102755/how-does-the-yak-130-fly-with-blocked-engine-inlets#comment287940_102756), MiG-29 was the first fighter to employ this double inlets system.

Apparently the twin design [M-346](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alenia_Aermacchi_M-346_Master) by Aermacchi (now Leonardo) doesn't possess this kind of feature ([source](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/be/e8/34/bee834d667c3c55b1dedd96ab376b52d.jpg)):

[image: M-346 cutaway]

Comment: It was also that FOD tolerant features, like intake grilles, was accounted for in Soviet design going way back, partly because of the expected imperatives in wartime, and partly because even in peacetime junk on the pavement was a never ending problem on Soviet bases.

Comment: You might want to add the MiG-29 as the first design which used intake covers and overwing intakes for take-off. See [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/51788/what-airplane-is-this-and-why-the-strange-inlets) or [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/7485/can-jet-airplanes-operate-on-rough-airfields/7496#7496) for more.

Comment: This is mentioned prominently in the Yak-130's Wikipedia page. However: what is the second grill adjacent to the above-wing intakes?